# Python вычитание дат

Tags: python, python-2.7

Требуется вычесть из заданного времени, настоящее.

```html
test = datetime.today().strftime("%H:%M")
test2 = timedelta(hours=22, minutes=30)
print(test-test2)
```

Казалось бы все просто, но в конечном результате мне нужно получить только кол-во минут оставшихся до этого времени. На данный момент завис на этом коде. Что можно сделать, чтобы это заработало?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно Вам нужно, `ребуется вычесть из заданного времени, настоящее.`, а в примере вы вычитаете из **текущего** времени 22 часа и 30 минут (т.е. заданное время?).  
Приведите, пожалуйста, пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Пример: у нас есть заданное время 22:05 и есть настоящее время, то есть которое сейчас на сервере, к примеру это 15:05. Теперь мы из заданного времени вычитаем настоящее время и получается ровно 7 часов. Но я считаю лучше было бы перевести это время в минуты, но это не проблема. Может случиться так что время получится отрицательным и это не должно вызвать проблем. Есть ли какой то вариант эио сделать?

Comment: Т.е. как я понял, работаем в пределах одного дня?  Допустим заданное время `22.05`, а текущее (настоящее) `23.35`, т.е. ответ будет отрицательным `-90 минут`, как в таком случае обрабатывать ответ, или это уже не важно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, то, что нужно.  И надеюсь понятно.

```
>>> import math
>>> from datetime import *
>>> tmp = datetime.today();
>>> static_date = datetime(tmp.year, tmp.month, tmp.day, 22, 5);
>>> static_date
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 17, 22, 5)
>>> current_date = datetime.today()
>>> current_date
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 17, 17, 2, 34, 792760)
>>> delta = static_date - current_date
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(seconds=18145, microseconds=207240)
>>>  #  Если секунды нужно "отсекать", можно вместо math.ceil() юзать просто int(), тогда и библиотеку лишнюю подключать не придётся.
>>> if ( delta.days == -1 ):
    out_minutes = math.ceil(delta.seconds / 60) - 24 * 60;
else:
    out_minutes = math.ceil(delta.seconds / 60);
>>> out_minutes
303  #  Количество минут от текущего до заданного
>>> test_date = datetime(tmp.year, tmp.month, tmp.day, 23, 35)
>>> delta = static_date - test_date
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=81000)
>>> if ( delta.days == -1 ):
    out_minutes = math.ceil(delta.seconds / 60) - 24 * 60;
else:
    out_minutes = math.ceil(delta.seconds / 60);


>>> out_minutes
-90  #  Отрицательное число, если текущее время больше заданного
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете только часы и минуты, то можете сделать так:

```
test = datetime.today().hour * 60 + datetime.today().minute
test2 = 22 * 60 + 30
print(test-test2)
```

В test у нас кол-во минут от 00:00 до текущего времени, а в test2 от 00:00 до 22:30